# Why QGraphicsItem's position is same even when it gets transform?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

[image: This is picture of rotated Item]

I am working on graphics project n I have a query, When I rotate `QGraphicsItem` around X-axis its bottomleft x position and topleft x position returns same value.

When I print `sceneBoundingRect().topLeft().x()` and `sceneBoundingRect().bottomLeft().x()` both values are same, but visually it has some change.
for that I have drawn `QGraphicsRectItem` around its `sceneBoundingRect`. 
Why it is so?
Here is my code

```
QTransform trans;
trans.translate(boundingRect().width()/2,boundingRect().height()/2);
trans.rotate(value, Qt::XAxis);
trans.translate(-boundingRect().width()/2,-boundingRect().height()/2);
setTransform(trans);
```

Comment: A bounding rectangle is a *rectangle* that bounds its contents. What else did you expect? - That's a serious question. Obviously you expected something else, so tell us what it is. The trapezoid still has to fit into a rectangle, so the fact that it is a trapezoid doesn't matter. Your transformation **happens** to transform a rectangle to a trapezoid in such a way that it preserves it bounding rectangle. That's all.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Actually I am looking for angle at which Item gets transformed also translated angle, so I was trying to get topleft and bottomleft. I thought they give me different values but it doesnt.

Comment: You need to check what coordinate system the bounding rectangle is given. Perhaps you expect it in some other coordinate system. The question isn't quite clear as to what you expect - it'd be cleared up by posting a complete, self contained example that demonstrates it. Your code snippets don't show the details necessary to easily understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually I was looking for translated angle got it by transform().dx() and transform().dy() functions. Thanks for your comments.